# Chrome browser can't get csrf from cookie

Tags: javascript, python, django

I copy the code from Django official site to get csrftoken from cookie.

```
function getCookie(name) {
let cookieValue = null;
if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
            cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
return cookieValue;
}   
csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

It originally works well, but in some days it can't work for Chrome anymore.
But it still works for Firefox.